# cassandra 3.11.2 memory consumption

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a cassandra-3.11.2 cluster with three nodes (cassandra1-3) in GCP (Google cloud) with Centos7 as OS. n1-highmem-2 with 5TB PD disk attached to each of them.

I used this blog as a guideline:

[System Memory Guidelines for Cassandra AWS](http://cloudurable.com/blog/cassandra_aws_system_memory_guidelines/index.html)

There are working for more than 90 days.
I let Cassandra to manage its memory without any intervention (XMS/XMX) but use G1 Settings.
Since the beginning of the cluster, it made 2-3 major compactions.

The three nodes were balanced (memory and disk space) until few days ago.
The memory usage of Cassandra #3 dropped from 70% to 52%. Disk usage dropped as well.
Everything works normal and I haven't saw anything strange in the log of #3.

Will #1 and #2 will be balanced to #3? Should I do something?

Comment: maybe it is related to:
default_time_to_live = 2592000 and gc_grace_seconds = 864000
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems forcing remove tombstones helps:

```
ALTER TABLE foo.bar WITH compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4', 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': ‘true’', 'tombstone_threshold': '0.1'};
```

After a short while, all 3 nodes started a compaction. Before altering the data partition was:

```
/dev/sdb        4.5T  2.9T  1.7T  63% /cassandra/data
```

After compaction

```
/dev/sdb        4.5T  1.8T  2.8T  39% /cassandra/data
```